# why does netcat work(to scan) faster in local host in virtual box but not for remote server?

Tags: virtualbox, port, nmap, netcat

I am using netcat to scan the ip of metasploitable2 from my kali machine in virtual box.netcat is very much faster to scan an ip of a local machine in virtual box. But when I am trying to scan a remote server's ip, netcat's performance reduces drastically. (I also use nmap for scanning purpose but learning netcat also) Here is my command to scan port of local machine in virtual box.

```
nc -z -v 10.0.2.4 1-1024
```

and here is my command to scan port of a remote server ip

```
nc -zvw 15 -n x.x.x.x 1-1024
```

I am trying in various ways but I could not get my expectation fill up. Thanks in advance.